# Arduino overridable functions

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to write a library where the user can define, inside a function, what should happen on a given event i.e. "`ON_CONNECTED() { do this }`".
This works so far, but i'd like to write a default command, if the user does not use the function, and that i can't figure out.

Here's my code.

### .ino file

```
#include <TestLibrary.h>

FUNCTION_TO_BE_CALLED() {
  Serial.println("This should be printing");
}

TestLib libTest;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  libTest.test();
  delay(1000);
}
```

### .h file

```
#ifndef TestLibrary_h
    #define TestLibrart_h
    #include <Arduino.h>
    #define FUNCTION_TO_BE_CALLED() void FunctionToBeCalled()
    FUNCTION_TO_BE_CALLED();

    class TestLib {
        public:
            TestLib();
            void test();
    };
#endif
```

### .cpp file

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <TestLibrary.h>

TestLib::TestLib() {}

/*void FunctionToBeCalled() {
    Serial.println("This is the default print");
}*/

void TestLib::test() {
    FunctionToBeCalled();
}
```

Where and how would i write the default function? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The normal way to approach this kind of problem is with virtual functions and a base class that provides the default implementation for the customizable parts, or with a function pointer to be assigned by the user that is set by default to a default implementation. An implementation-dependent possibility is also to exploit gcc/ld's support for weak symbols, and provide the default version of your function as a weak symbol, which can be replaced without errors by a user provided one.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Thanks. The '__attribute__((weak))' was a great help. If you write a answer I'll mark that as answered.

Comment: And it's done. But consider also the two alternative methods, as explained in the answer the weak symbols method has several shortcomings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(moving from the comments)

The normal way to approach this kind of problem is with virtual functions and a base class that provides the default implementation for the customizable parts: you provide the base class, the user can drive from it and replace the `virtual` functions with his custom ones and put an instance of his class in some base class pointer (possibly through some setter method of your class), that your code will use to invoke the custom stuff.

Another (similar) possibility is to provide a function pointer to be assigned by the user, that is set by default to a default implementation.

Finally, an implementation-dependent possibility is also to exploit gcc/ld's support for weak symbols, and provide the default version of your function as a weak symbol, which can be replaced without errors by a user provided one. This is not portable, but has the advantage of being surely completely resolved at compile time and is arguably simpler to use for the inexperienced user of the library - all he has to do is to (possibly) write his function with the given name. On the other hand, this approach is intrinsically limited to a single customization in the whole program - all the `TestLib` instances will use the same custom event handler, while with the other two methods the customization is per-instance.

Comment: Great! I used weak symbols for this, but i will be reading on the class based with virtual functions, this sounds interesting for another project. If you know of a good article on that, a link would be appreciated.